# Ana B'choach - Private prayer or Sing-Along song?

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, mysticism-kabbalah, tzibur-community, loud-quiet

Many people have the custom to recite the prayer "Ana B'choach" after the initial six chapters of Tehillim said in Kabbalas Shabbos and before "Lecha Dodi". Based on the fact that it references certain uncommon names of God and that the custom's origin seems to be the Sh'la, I would identify this prayer as being of a kabbalistic nature.

Now, I don't know if this has basis, but I've always felt that kabbalistic practices should be kept to one's self as private practices. This is why, although I personally do not recite the prayer, I think it is proper that it is not customarily recited out loud, but rather quietly in an undertone.

However, this past week, the *chazzan* of the minyan I was praying with decided to have everyone sing it out loud in unison to a popular tune. This made me extremely uneasy.

So I ask: Is there anything really wrong with what this *chazzan* did? Is there a reason why the prevalent custom is to recite it quietly and individually?

Comment: Comments from the down-voters, if you please?

Comment: The author is R' Nehunya Ben Hakana (a *tanna*), and the special intentions are from the Arizal.

Comment: @HachamGabriel, Yes indeed. I meant that the custom of reciting it on Friday night before Lecha Dodi seems to originate with the Sh'la.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about that...

Comment: [Here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42571&st=&pgnum=127) it is. My siddur seems to indicate that this is the source. Although, you never know.

Comment: I bet you are right, because I don't believe ever seeing the Arizal saying to say it. And, Harav Musafi says not to say it Erev Shabbat (seemingly because the Ari doesn't mention it).

Comment: re: _"kabbalistic practices should be kept to one's self as private practices"_. Did you mean only those that are incorporated in prayer? Because there are kabbalistic practices that are public, or at least are sung in public, e.g. "azamer", "asader", "bnei heicholo"....

Comment: re:  "but I've always felt that kabbalistic practices should be kept to one's self as private practices"  So you don't do the other 6 sections of Kabbalat Shabbat either then?  The whole custom is Kabalistic practice!!!

Comment: @avi, I do recite the rest of Kabbalas Shabbos even though the custom has kabbalistic origins. After all, it was accepted by virtually all Jewish communities even those usually wary of kabbalistic practices. Besides, it's only chapters of Tehillim. Ana B'choach, on the other hand, is more blatantly kabbalistic.

Comment: @Jake if it is the accepted custom of your Community/Nusach to say it than I don't know what heter you have not to say it. Minhag Yisroel Torah and you have no right to pick and choose based on your feelings.

Comment: @eramm, Thank you for your concern, and I will take your comment as a polite interest in how I justify not saying "Ana B'koach" while everyone else does. I am of German ("Yekkish") descent, and the German custom is to *not* say Ana B'koach (among other things, such as B'rich Sh'meih). That I don't say it is similar to an Ashkenazic person not saying the Sefardic additions to various prayers whilst attending a Sefardic shul, which is quite justified according to many poskim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Harav Musafi Shelit"a says in his lecture (Ana Bechoah) that the entire point is to have the special intentions while reciting the words. However, the Haye Adam doesn't hold of people in that generation (Kal Wahomer now) intending on the Arizal's intention.

Of course, as the Ben Ish Hai writes in his Sefer Emunat Atich, before intending the Kabalistic intentions, you must understand the simple meaning of the words.

Therefor, as long as they have the Peshat in mind, it is okay to recite prayer aloud.

http://doresh-tzion.co.il/LessonSearch.aspx?st=%u05d0%u05e0%u05d0+%u05d1%u05db%u05d7

Just found this Q&A 16167 from Harav Musafi Shelit"a

> **שאלה** - 16167
>   לכבוד הרב שלום רב
>   יש מנגינה שנפוצה בציבור, שרים את "אנא בכח גדולת ימינך" במנגינה, וחוזרים על חלק מהמילים, האם יש בזה בעיה?
>   **תשובה**
>   אין בעיה במנגינה וגם במה שחוזרים עליה, יש בעיה בשיבושי הלשון שם בשבא נע ונח ודגש ורפה וחבל.‏

He says there is no problem to sing it and even when you repeat the words. However, if you change the Shva Na into Nah there is a problem

Comment: So is the reason that people generally do it quietly to themselves because that is more proper, or it's just like people say the rest of kabbalas shabbos to themselves (besides for the *chazzan*'s parts and Lecha Dodi)? And what about the "Baruch Shem..." at the end?

Comment: @jake it's just like the other parts of Kabalas Shabbos. About the Baruch Shem Inyan, some Posekim hold you can say it aloud even, but some disagree (in general).

Answer (score 1):

The Chabad minhag is to specifically say this prayer quietly. I know for sure sources mention saying it quietly during the Kabbolas Shabbos prayer, but have not seen any sources regarding conduct during other services.

http://chabad-il.org/hit/hit212.htm#6  (in Hebrew)

In the new [print](http://store.kehotonline.com/index.php?stocknumber=EP-STH.AB) of Tehillas Hashem published by Kehos, this law is brought down.